# Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug'

Tags: react-native

*After `npm install react-native-gesture-handler`, it gives me that error.*

*Error after `react-native run-android`*
[image]

*after that this error comes out:*

[image]

I didnt understand what is problem here ?

Comment: I solved this issue with this : npm install -g @react-native-community/cli

Comment: are you using the react-native 0.60.+ or older version?

Comment: I use latest version. I solved that with using "npm install -g @react-native-community/cli "